# Python script to read all the PDFs in a folder and rename it to the first date it finds in each of the PDFs

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, automation, python-dateutil

My code runs but only reads the first PDF file and renames it then it gives me an error as Document closed and then ends the script.

here is the code as below:

```
import fitz
from dateutil.parser import parse
import os

# Get the path of the folder containing the PDFs
pdf_folder = 'E:/PYTHON/dummyData/'

# Iterate over all files in the folder
for file_name in os.listdir(pdf_folder):
    if file_name.endswith('.pdf'):
        file_path = os.path.join(pdf_folder, file_name)
        
        # Open the PDF file in binary mode
        with fitz.open(file_path) as pdf_file:

            # Extract text from all pages of the PDF
            text = ''
            for page_num in range(pdf_file.page_count):
                page = pdf_file.load_page(page_num)
                text += page.get_text()

            # Search for dates in the text
            dates = []
            for word in text.split():
                try:
                    date = parse(word, fuzzy=True)
                    if len(word) == 10 or len(word) == 11:
                        dates.append(date)
                
                except (ValueError, OverflowError):
                    # Handle the error and continue to the next value
                    pass
            pdf_file.close()                          

            # Rename the PDF file to the first date found
            if dates:
                new_name = dates[0].strftime('%d-%m-%y ') + file_name
                #pdf_file.close()
                os.rename(file_path, os.path.join(pdf_folder, new_name))
                print(f'The file {file_name} has been renamed to {new_name}.')
            else:
                print(f'No dates were found in the PDF {file_name}.')
```

this is the error that I am getting

[image]

every time I run it only renames the first PDF in the folder and then gives this error and ends.

Comment: Remove `pdf_file.close()`. It will be closed automatically at the end of the `with` block.

Comment: You should consider using a different naming convention, such as `03_20_2023_filename.pdf` versus `20-20-2023 filename.pdf`